# Error when delete data using foreignKey in adonisjs

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, delete-row, adonis.js

I have a problem when try to delete my data in adonisjs, when i enter primarykey as parameter to delete it success, but when i'm try to enter another parameter it doesn't work.

This is my route to access endpoint:

`Route.delete('customer_wishlist/:id_product', 'WishlistController.delete')`

`id_product` isn't primarykey, but foreignkey. This is in my controller to process delete:

```
async delete ({params, response}) {
    console.log(params)
    const wishlist = await Wishlist.find(params.id_product)
    console.log(wishlist)

    if (!wishlist) {
        return response.status(404).json({data: 'Resource not found'})
    }

   await wishlist.delete()
   return response.status(200).json({status:true, data: wishlist})
}
```

The result of console.log above `const wishlist = await Wishlist.find(params.id_product)` is json id, this match with parameter. But the result of console log below `const wishlist = await Wishlist.find(params.id_product)` is null.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find()` is only for primaryKey

try it :

`.findBy()` -> [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_findby_findbyorfail)

```js
await Wishlist.findBy('id_product', params.id_product)
```

**! Returns the first matching record**